# Expo video Orientation LANDSCAPE not working on ANDROID

Tags: android, react-native, expo

my code is working just fine on IOS the orientation work fine when rotating the phone but in Android if i chose full screen and rotate the phone nothing happens (screen orientation stay PORTRAIT)

```
          const { width: DEVICE_WIDTH, height: DEVICE_HEIGHT } = 
          Dimensions.get("window");
           const VIDEO_CONTAINER_HEIGHT = (DEVICE_HEIGHT * 2.0) / 5.0 - 
          FONT_SIZE * 2;   
      _onReadyForDisplay = event => {
  const widestHeight =
    (DEVICE_WIDTH * event.naturalSize.height) / event.naturalSize.width;
  if (widestHeight > VIDEO_CONTAINER_HEIGHT) {
    this.setState({
      videoWidth:
        (VIDEO_CONTAINER_HEIGHT * event.naturalSize.width) /
        event.naturalSize.height,
      videoHeight: VIDEO_CONTAINER_HEIGHT
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      videoWidth: DEVICE_WIDTH,
      videoHeight:
        (DEVICE_WIDTH * event.naturalSize.height) / 
 event.naturalSize.width
    });
    }
   };
   <Video
        ref={this._mountVideo}
        source={{ uri: article.video_version }}
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        isMuted={false}
        shouldPlay
        isLooping
        style={[
          styles.video,
          {
            width: this.state.videoWidth,
            height: this.state.videoHeight
          }
        ]}
        useNativeControls
        onFullscreenUpdate={this._onFullscreenUpdate}
        resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
        onReadyForDisplay={this._onReadyForDisplay}
       />
```

Comment: Use this library to solve your problem.:"react-native-orientation"